# Apply command to all files in a directory

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting

I want to apply the following command to all the files in the current directory

```
clustalw -align -infile=*here goes the input filename* -outfile=*here goes the output filename*
```

I also want the output filename to be the same as the input plus ".aln". For example:

```
clustalw -align -infile=nexus0000.fna -outfile=nexus000.fna.aln
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use for loop and globbing by filename extension:

```
for file in *.fna; do
    clustalw -align -infile="$file" -outfile="$file.aln"
done
```

If you want to use a single command, you can use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.fna" -exec clustalw -infile {} -outfile {}.aln  \;
```

Comment: If you want the equivalent of `-iname "*.fna"`, that would be `for file in *.[fF][nN][aA]` or use the extensions that some shells have for case insensitive globs. Note that `find` will include dotfiles though shell globs won't by default.